# Grobner basis calculation while keeping track of the change of basis

Tags: groebner-bases

Can one compute a Groebner basis for a polynomial ideal in *Mathematica*, while simultaneously getting the change of basis matrix?

Comment: `GroebnerBasis\`BasisAndConversionMatrix]` does this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I tried this, but calling ``GroebnerBasis`BasisAndConversionMatrix[{p1,...,pm}]`` returns a basis that somehow doesn't reduce the polynomial I am trying to reduce fully. I am left with a remainder term even thought the groebner basis computed with Maple using the same p1,...,pn does reduce the given polynomial fully. I thought it might be because there are some symbolic constants in p1,...,pn, but when I try calling ``GroebnerBasis`BasisAndConversionMatrix[{p1,...,pm},{x,y,z}]`` I just get back $Failed.

Comment: Can't really help without a concrete example...